# Use variables selected from DISTLM multivariate regressions in CAP

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, canonical-correlation

I would like to know if the following analysis strategy is correct conceptually, if it makes sense. I found difference in fish assemblage structure between two estuarine sectors, through PERMANOVA. I would like to identify what environmental factors are associated with this difference. Then, I used DISTLM (Distance‐based linear modelling) utilising information criteria to find the best model of variables related to the multivariate data cloud. I then run a canonical analysis of principal coordinates (CAP) to find axes maximizing this spatial differences with linear combinations of variables from the best DISTLM model. I'm not so sure if I can use these variables from DISTLM in the CAP. If not, can anyone suggest an alternative analysis strategy?

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what your end game is for the data.

If you are trying to find relationships within your data set, I would use PERMANOVA to test if the fish assemblages are different. I would use SIMPER if you are interested in which species are driving those differences. The BEST routine could then be used to indicate which combination of environmental variables best resembles the fish assemblages' similarities (the BEST correlated variables between data sets). To depict all of that, use nMDS plots with the BEST variables as vectors and, if applicable and not messy, bubble plots of species. CAP is a follow-up to PERMANOVA that can be used to visualize a data cloud when the results of PERMANOVA are hard to interpret on an nMDS plot (i.e. stress > 2).

If you want more than "which environmental variables correlate with the biotic ones", DISTLIM will construct the best combination of environmental variables that accounts for the variation seen in the fish assemblage (basically a regression). I would use the step-wise procedure to test which variables should be in the model with AICc. I would also tell the procedure to use dbRDA to plot the data according to that model.

You will usually come to similar conclusions using either path, it will just matter how you want to talk about it.  I've found that the following video explains these concepts pretty well: www.youtube.com/watch?v=1iCloSQcwjk

*With all of these, you will need to think through which similarity or distance is most appropriate for your data and if a transformation or normalization is needed beforehand.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will use the DISTLM rotine followed by dbRDA ordinations, which, in fact, seems more appropriate.